# How do I say "It doesn't matter if..."

Tags: grammar, mandarin

E.g. It doesn't matter if you are ugly (or not)

你丑不丑都没关系 or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

"你丑不丑都没关系" is good and sounds native. You could say "你丑不丑都无所谓" as well.

Comment: 都没关系 can be replaced by 也（都）不要紧 cf。 ＂实用英汉词典＂matter II v 要紧：对我没有什么要紧，你如果赶不上这趟火车也不要紧，因为梢晚一点还有一趟

Comment: in "你丑不丑都没关系" , 丑(ugly) is an adjective, you can replace it with a verb, for example 去 - " "你去不去都没关系" or a verb phrase, for example: "回家" -  " 你回不回家都没关系